# Facebook Login Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift3, parse-server

I am trying to login using Facebook and Parse. I have the following code in my `viewDidLoad` of the initial `viewcontroller`.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let permissions = ["public_profile"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) { (user, error) in

        if let error = error{
            print(error)
        }
        else{
            if let user = user{
                print(user)   
            }   
        }   
    }  
}
```

I am not able to redirect the app to Facebook login when the app first launches. But when I segue from a different page to the initial page, Facebook login works as expected. I am not able to debug what is going on here and have spent countless hours on it without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you move your code to [viewDidAppear](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let permissions = ["public_profile"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) { (user, error) in

        if let error = error{

            print(error)

        }

        else{
            if let user = user{
                print(user)   
            }   
        }   
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hey it worked. But my user is not getting printed. I debugged and control does not enter the block at all after I authorise the app. Not does it print out an error message

Comment: Hello, can you move your print to show user and error even if there are nil

Comment: The problem is that the control doesn't even get inside the error and the user. It skips the main braces completely. I am not sure why

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath to see what's happening it is possible to print variables outside the braces ?

Comment: Yes. I am able to use print() outside the braces. This is frustrating. There is not proper documentation for Parse Facebook login. Their documentation is either outdated or not so clear

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath Perfect try to print error and user ☺ Yes the documentation is not updated and not so clear

Comment: Cannot print error and user as I am outside PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) { (user, error) in{}

Comment: You can try something like that ? PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) { (user, error) in{ 
print(user)
print(error)
}

Comment: I tried this. Its not working. Like I said. The control doesn't get inside the main braces of the loginInBackground{}

Comment: Have you setup the Facebook SDK in the AppDelegate ?

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        ///Your setup
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook(applicationLaunchOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

Comment: Hey Juien. Yes I have both the methods in app delegate

Comment: Do you have this method in the app delegate too ? 

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
         FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath I think you have setup the Info.plist ?

Comment: Yes I have created the entries in info.plist. Hey Julien. I was wondering if you had a boiler plate Project that I could try code for Facebook integration ? I am guessing you must have integrated Facebook and Parse in the past. I would really appreciate it

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath No problem, I think it is better for you, I will send you a little project with Parse and Facebook SDK as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks a ton Julien. Really appreciate it. I have been struggling with this for over a week now. No proper documentation on Facebook or on Parse. Its like a nightmare. My email id is      -    varunbabu008@gmail.com

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath Thank you 

Comment: Please replace your old function to: 

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }